# Bootstrap form validation, require 1 of 3 text fields?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm using bootstrap 4 with the built in form validation. I can require one text filed like this

```
<div class="col-6 mb-3">
   <label for="field">field</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field" name="field" placeholder="" value="" required>
   <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please enter.
   </div>
</div>
```

But how do I do if I have 3 text fields (like above) in a group and the user only needs to type something on one of the files.

Ex

All fields empty - bootstrap validation fails.

User writes something in text field 2 and 3 - bootstrap validation passes.

User writes something in text field 1 - bootstrap validation passes.

User writes something in text field 3 - bootstrap validation passes.

The user only needs to write something in at least 1 of the 3 fields to pass validation. If all 3 are empty the validation fails.

Comment: I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/troyb12/9anb8gh0/1/) for you.  Is this what you are looking for?  I am checking if at least one input has a value.. if yes or no display alert.. but you can edit that to do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm asuming that you've a registration form with 4 fields, one of the 3 fields (username, email & contact) is required and password field is required.

Add jQuery **validate.js** in your page

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js

**HTML**

```
<form id='register-form' action='#' method='post'>
   <label>Username</label>
   <input type='text' name='username' id='user_name' class='' />

   <label>Email</label>
   <input type='email' name='email' id='email_id' class='' />

   <label>Contact No</label>
   <input type='text' name='contact' id='contact_no' class='' />

   <label>Password</label>
   <input type='text' name='password' id='pass' class='' />

   <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
// custom validation method
    $.validator.addMethod("require_any", function (value, element, param) {
        var is_filled=false; // flag to check input is empty or filled
        $.each(param.split(/\|/), function (i, input_id) { // split input ids
            if($('#'+ input_id).val()!==''){
                return is_filled=true; // if any empty input found break the loop
            }
        });
        return is_filled; 
    });
// submit form and apply validation rules
$('#register-form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

        }).validate({
            rules: {
              username: {
                 require_any: 'user_name|email_id|contact_no' //pass the ids
                 },
              email: {
                 require_any: 'user_name|email_id|contact_no', //pass the ids
                 email: true // for email validation
                 },
              contact: {
                 require_any: 'user_name|email_id|contact_no' //pass the ids
                 },
              password: {
                 required: true // password is required
                 }
            },
            messages: {
               require_any: 'Please provide one of Username or Email or Contact',
               required: 'Password field is required.' // by default message 'This field is required.'
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                 // validation success code ...
               }
        });
```